# Passing an object to a controller from a selection box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a selection box that displays the results of a search function(the results are different events).  The user is to have the option of either viewing the details of the event or selecting the event to work with.  Since I already have the objects from the database I want to pass the selected object to the correct controller action.  When I try to do this the object is passed to the controller as a string.  The code I have is below

```
<h2>Search Results</h2>

<p>
        <%= form_tag :action => :event_options %>
        <p><select name="event" size = 5>
        <%@events.each do |event|%>    
            <option value="<%= event%>"><%=event.name%></option> 
        <%end%>
        </select></p>
        <%= submit_tag "Event Details", :name=>"details" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Select Event", :name=>"select" %>

    </form>
```

The event options action of my controller is like this:

```
def event_options
  @event = params[:event]

  if params['details']
    redirect_to :action=>:view_event_detail, :event=>@event
  else
    redirect_to :action=>:select_event
  end
```

I just want the entire event object to be passed into the event_options action and then sent to the action based on what submit button the user clicked.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A select option's value can't be an object. It doesn't know what objects are. It just wants a string, like "1" or "yes" or something. So, when you just put in `event`, it does a to_s on it.

What you should do instead is use `event.id` as the value, and in your controller just do `Event.find` to grab the event object and work with it.

Comment: I considered that approach already, but the thing is at this point I already have the objects from the db. I'd really rather not do another query for an object that I already have.  Are there any other options besides select boxes that can give me the same functionality but allow to use the object I already have?

Comment: They actually will do the retrieval from cache, and not go directly to the database. If you have rails server open, you will see when it Loads from the DB and when it uses Cache.